# I tried to use facebook feed dialog but it's not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Just trying to post feed to my wall, but got errors message

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

here is my code

```
var app_url = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
var fb_app_id = xxxxxxxxxx;
// When init
FB.init({
    appId: fb_app_id, 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
    frictionlessRequests: true, 
    useCachedDialogs: true, 
    oauth: true
});
// When posting
FB.ui({
    method : 'feed',
    link : 'http://apps.facebook.com/' + fb_app_id,
    redirect_uri : app_url + 'facebook/index.php',
    picture : app_url + 'icon/fb_feed_lvup.png',
    name : 'My Game',
    caption : 'Player level up to ' + level + '!!',
    description : 'Congratulation :D'
},
function callback(response) {
    // Callback after feed posted...
    console.log('publishStory UI response: ', response);
});
```

I doesn't know that it's related to my app setting which not set "App Domains" or not ?

I can't set it because the host doesn't have Domain name I'm just using IP address to set an URL setting.

Comment: It's a url of my website.

Comment: The problem is that you have not given the same url (`app_url`) in the app settings . Please check again and define the App Domain also.

Comment: Okay, but I can't set App Domain as IP address and my customer didn't provided Domain name so may I have to test on my hosting, Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: 1 thing, the `app_url` must be `http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME`, why are you redirecting him from the app to the website?

Comment: In fact, I don't want it to redirect to anywhere, I have try to not define it but it's not work and return same error message as I mention in question then I try to define it but it's still not work :(

Comment: I previously used PHP SDK but facebook won't allow to use graph api to post feed to other users wall so I want to change to use dialog.

Comment: `post feed to other users wall` this feature has been removed now. You can now use feed for posting on your own wall only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [API Error Code: 191, API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10374964/api-error-code-191-api-error-description-the-specified-url-is-not-owned-by-th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

Copy the `Site URL` from the app settings to the `redirect_url` and then check if it works.

I checked, else everything is fine.